# Simplifying $xy^2-\frac{x(-xy-1)^2}{(x-1)^2}+2y\left(\frac{-xy-1}{x-1}-1\right)+\left(\frac{-xy-1}{x-1}-1\right)^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, rational-functions

I have the following equation

$$xy^2-\frac{x(-xy-1)^2}{(x-1)^2}+2y\left(\frac{-xy-1}{x-1}-1\right)+\left(\frac{-xy-1}{x-1}-1\right)^2=0$$

which I was trying to simplify. I know the solution is
$$\frac{x(y+1)(3y-1)}{x-1}=0$$ which gives $y=-1$ or $y=1/3$.

WolframAlpha suggests first expanding and collecting in terms of $y$:

$$1+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}+y\left(-2-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{2x}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{2x}{x-1}-\frac{2x^2}{(x-1)^2}\right)+y^2\left(x-\frac{2x}{x-1}+\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{x^3}{(x-1)^2}\right)=0$$

and then "factoring the left side into a product with five terms" i.e the solution. Is this factorization obvious? How do I factor the LHS by hand, or is there another simpler way?

Comment: Why do you call it “polynomial”? What you have written is an equality between a rational fraction and $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This is true, I have now edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: And I have edited the tags.

Comment: What is problematic about putting everything over a common denominator? The factor $x-1$ in the numerator is readily identified (if it cancels) by putting $x=1$ in the numerator - if everything cancels you have a factor and can divide.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{-xy-1}{x-1}-1=-\frac{x(y+1)}{x-1}.$

So taking out a common factor x and putting every term over the common denominator $(x-1)^{2}$ we have:

$$x(\frac{y^{2}(x-1)^{2}-(-xy-1)^{2}-2y(y+1)(x-1)+x(y+1)^{2}}{(x-1)^{2}})=x(\frac{-3y^{2}(x-1)-2y(x-1)+(x-1)}{x-1})=\frac{x(-3y^{2}-2y+1)}{x-1}=-\frac{x(y+1)(3y-1)}{x-1}=0.$$